# Default Udev rules

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device, udev

If i have not defined my own set of udev rules what will be the default udev rules and how can I know them. Consider this question in the context of dynamically registered character driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the default udev rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/` but you may also want to check `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and `/run/udev/rules.d/` also for your specific distro.

I pulled this info directly from `man 7 udev`